# Moving shared methods to a Util class in Java?

Tags: java, class, inheritance, static

I have the following service implementation:

```
public class DataServiceImpl implements DataService {

    private static final String SHEET_TITLE = "export.permission.sheetTitle";

    private XSSFWorkbook workbook;
    private XSSFSheet sheet;
    private AtomicInteger rowCount;

    @Override
    public MultipartFile export() throws IOException {

        createSheet(SHEET_TITLE);

        // code omitted for brevity
    }

    private void createSheet(String title) {
        workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        sheet = workbook.createSheet(title);
        rowCount = new AtomicInteger(0);
    }
}
```

In this class, I have some methods e.g. `createSheet` and I want to move this method to a `Util` class, because other similar class will also use this method.

However, as some variables e.g. `workbook`, `sheet`, `rowCount` are used in the other method in this service, I don't know if I should pass these variables to the Util method `createSheet` and then return from it, or another proper way. So, how should I move `createSheet` method to my Util class and use it from different classes?

**Update:** I also have the following methods. Shoul I move them Util class? Or should I create a class for `createMultipartFile()` method just as `createSheet()` method and move only `writeTitles()` method to Util class?

```
private MultipartFile createMultipartFile(String title, String extension) throws IOException {
    File outputFile = File.createTempFile(TextBundleUtil.read(title), extension);    
    workbook.write(outputStream);

    final FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(outputFile);

    final String fileName = TextBundleUtil.read(title).concat(extension);
    return new MockMultipartFile(fileName,
            fileName, CONTENT_TYPE, IOUtils.toByteArray(input));
}


private static void writeTitles(Row row, List<String> titles, XSSFCellStyle style) {
    for (int i = 0; i < titles.size(); i++) {
        Cell cell = row.createCell(i);
        cell.setCellValue(titles.get(i));
        cell.setCellStyle(style);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think in the case you comment, you need split your class in two, one with the functionality you need, and other with the variable, just seeing what you post, you can't simply move your class into another and extend.

Comment: @AL Any example please instead of trying to explain something only words?

Comment: It seems like what you’re doing needs to be stateful? But things like services and Util classes should not have conversational state because they’re typically used concurrently by different users. Having shared state for either case seems wrong.

Comment: Generally speaking, if you have a class named `Util` or `XUtil` which is just filled to the brim with a haphazard collection of static methods, that's crappy design. There are times when it's the most proper way to go, but it is rare. Case in point: `java.util.Collections` (which is a 'Utils' class, just not named that way) has `sort`... but these days so does `list` itself which is where it should have lived in the first place.

Comment: @NathanHughes What about the approach that Cris posted as answer? Is that a proper way?

Comment: @rzwitserloot What are you mentioning?

Comment: Kris’ answer is good. Except having his object as an instance member of the service is questionable as I said before.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40996614/whats-the-best-practice-for-creating-stateless-utility-classes-in-java.

Comment: But what is the context here ? Is this a web app deployed in a cluster? Is it a desktop application ? Or something else?

Comment: @NathanHughes Which instance member do you mean?

Comment: @NathanHughes It is a web app.

Answer (score 3):

One of the good approaches will be to delegate those properties as a separate object. See below:

```java
public class WorkSheet{
     private XSSFWorkbook workbook;
     private XSSFSheet sheet;
     private AtomicInteger rowCount;
     public WorkSheet(String title) {
       this.workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
       this.sheet = workbook.createSheet(title);
       this.rowCount = new AtomicInteger(0);
   }
   public XSSFWorkbook getWorkbook() {
     return workbook;
   }
   public XSSFSheet getSheet() {
     return sheet;
   }
   public AtomicInteger getRowCount() {
     return rowCount;
   }  
 }
```

```java
public class DataServiceImpl implements DataService {

    private static final String SHEET_TITLE = "export.permission.sheetTitle";
    private WorkSheet workSheet;
    
    @Override
    public MultipartFile export() throws IOException {

        workSheet = new WorkSheet(SHEET_TITLE);
        // code omitted for brevity
        
        //then use like workSheet.getSheet()
    } 
}
```

Now you can use that object anywhere you need.

Comment: Thanks a lot Cris, seems to good I will try. In this scene, I think there is no need to use Util class and `createSheet` method. I can directly set my `workSheet` variable and get its variable via `get` methods. Is that true?

Comment: Yes. You can extend it in any way you like. I just proposed an approach. feel free to accept as an answer, if this solves your problem

Comment: I will accept of course, but before that I need to be sure if there is a more proper way. I think it is impossible to set the local variables via Util methods in Util class. Is that true?

Comment: Is there any other way that you could suggest?

Comment: You want to avoid using util methods as much as possible. Util methods are very rarely a good idea. Kris has a perfect solution for what you want to do.

Comment: Could you please see my **Update** in the question? I also have the following methods. Should I move them Util class? Or should I create a class for `createMultipartFile()` method just as `createSheet()` method and move only `writeTitles()` method to Util class?

Comment: No you (probably) shouldn't. If you need the methods somewhere else you can either use delegation or inheritance. I recommend to open another question instead of editing your already existing one to ask another question.